# How to use mapply to perform function on columns of two lists in R?

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, mapply

I am trying to calculate a population genetic statistic (mean FST) on the nth elements of two lists in R. This stat requires calculating the population variance, which R does not have a native function for. I can not figure out how to convert my code which works for a dataframe (2 rows), to code that works for 2 lists.

Here is an example of code that works for the two row dataframe:

```
#Generate dataframe data
popa <- abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))
popb <- 1-abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))
totalpop <- rbind(popa, popb)

#Make population variance function
pvar <- function(x) {
  sum((x - mean(x))**2) / length(x)
}

#Calculate statistic on each column, and take the global mean
MeanFST <- mean(apply(totalpop, 2, pvar)/((apply(totalpop, 2, mean))*(1-(apply(totalpop, 2, mean)))))
```

But I don't know how to convert this code to one that operates on lists

```
#Generate lists data
listA <- list()
listB <- list()
for(i in 1:30){
  listA[[i]] <- abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))
  listB[[i]] <- 1 - abs(rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))
}
```

I've tried using Map like this,

```
results <- Map(function(X,Y) {
  mean(apply(totalpop, 2, pvar)/((apply(totalpop, 2, mean))*(1-(apply(totalpop, 2, mean)))))
}, X = listA, Y = listB)
```

but obviously this won't work, because it requires "totalpop" which doesn't exist when I am calculating stats on two lists (only when I combine two dataframes).

How can I make this MeanFST calculation on two lists?

Comment: IN the `Map`, where are you using the `X` and `Y`.  it seems that the 'totalpop' is repeated

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply/sapply` after splitting the data by column

```
 mean(sapply(asplit(totalpop, 2), function(x) pvar(x)/(mean(x) * (1 - mean(x)))))
```

---

Or with `apply` and a lambda function

```
mean(apply(totalpop, 2, function(x) pvar(x)/(mean(x) * (1 - mean(x)))))
```

---

The `Map` part, we may need to `cbind` the two `list` elements and use the same code with `apply` or `sapply`

```
unlist(Map(function(u, v) mean(apply(cbind(u, v), 2, 
   function(x) pvar(x)/(mean(x) * (1 - mean(x))))),  listA, listB))
```